# Escape string with single quotes in PHP for SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, escaping

I would like to store the following string in the field of an SQLite table:

```
$string = "Einstein's equation";
```

Is there a function to do so in a safe way? Obviously

```
SQLite3::escapeString($string);
```

does not work. Instead it will return `Einstein"s equation`.

I read that in SQL one is supposed to use double single quotes for single quotes, i.e., `Einstein''s equation`. However, if I try to make it safe `SQLite3::escapeString("Einstein''s equation")` returns `Einstein""s equation`. Is that a bug of `escapeString`?

What would be the correct way to escape a string with single quotes properly?

Comment: Use Prepared Statements to get it escapaed for you

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am quite a beginner in SQLite and never heard about "Prepare Statements". Could you direct me to some place where I can read about it or even give an example?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: use sqlite_escape_string

Comment: Unfortunately, PHP complains about "Call to undefined function  sqlite_escape_string()".

Comment: i'd suggest use `PDO` with prepared statements http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that.